# javascript variable showing as undefined in Elevator Saga learning tool

Tags: javascript, arrays, scoping

I'm new to JavaScript, coming over from Swift. Trying it out code-learning challenges at  http://play.elevatorsaga.com/
and some behavior is tough to grasp. In the following code, I setup floor & elevator objects. I am trying to get the elevator to get the floor it is about to pass's button request (if someone has pressed that floor's up or down button to call the elevator) 
- in the code `console.log(" (x) passing_floor - Same direction requested");`

However the logs I get tell me that the up/downRequests are undefined

```
passing_floor 2 up
upRequest:  undefined
downRequest:  undefined
```

Is the issue with initialization? scoping? What is the proper way to achieve what I am trying to do?

```
{
init: function(elevators, floors) {
   function initializeElevator(elevator){
       elevator.on("floor_button_pressed", function(floorNum) {
           elevator.goToFloor(floorNum);
       });
       elevator.on("idle", function() {
           elevator.goToFloor(0);   
       });

       elevator.on("passing_floor", function(floorNum, direction) {
           if ((floorNum.upRequest) && (direction =='up')) {
               floorNum.upRequest = false;
               console.log(" (x) passing_floor - Same direction requested");
           } else if ((floorNum.downRequest) && (direction == 'down')) {
               floorNum.downRequest = false;
               console.log(" (x) passing_floor - Same direction requested");
           } else {
               console.log("passing_floor " + floorNum + " " + direction);
               console.log("upRequest:  "   + floorNum.upRequest);
               console.log("downRequest:  " + floorNum.downRequest);
           }
       });   
   }

    function initializeFloor(floor){
        var upRequest = false;
        var downRequest = false;
        floor.on("up_button_pressed", function() {
             this.upRequest = true;
        });
        floor.on("down_button_pressed", function() {
            this.downRequest = true;
        });
    }

elevators.forEach(initializeElevator);
floors.forEach(initializeFloor); 

},
update: function(dt, elevators, floors) { }
}
```

Thank you for taking the time to help me understand Javascript a bit more, trying out W3School to get around it, but let me know if you have better sites I should look at..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to proceed with the desired behavior by creating an "array" of floors that were global - I'm not sure if this was a scoping issue or something else though!

```
{
    init: function(elevators, floors) {
        var floorArray = new Array(floors.length); 
        var elevatorOnFloor = new Array(floors.length);


        //the init function populates the listeners for the elevator objects
       function initializeElevator(elevator){
           elevator.on("floor_button_pressed", function(floorNum) {
               elevator.goToFloor(floorNum, true);
           });
           elevator.on("idle", function() {
               elevator.goToFloor(0);   
           });

           elevator.on("passing_floor", function(floorNum, direction) { 
               if ((floorArray[floorNum] == 1) && (direction =='up')) {
                   floorArray[floorNum] = 0;
                   elevator.goToFloor(floorNum, true);  
                   console.log("picking someone else going UP");
                   elevatorOnFloor[floorNum]+=1;
                   console.log("elevators per floor:"+ elevatorOnFloor );

               } else if ((floorArray[floorNum] = 2) && (direction == 'down')) {
                   floorArray[floorNum] = 0;
                   elevator.goToFloor(floorNum, true);  
                   console.log("picking someone else going DOWN");
                   elevatorOnFloor[floorNum]-=1;
                   console.log("elevators per floor:" + elevatorOnFloor + floorArray );
               } else {
                   console.log("passing_floor " + floorNum + " " + direction);
                   if (direction =='up') {
                   elevatorOnFloor[floorNum]+=1;
                   } else {
                       elevatorOnFloor[floorNum]-=1;
                   }
               }


           });




       }








        function initializeFloor(floor){
            floor.on("up_button_pressed", function() {
                 floorArray[floor] = 1;
            });
            floor.on("down_button_pressed", function() {
                 floorArray[floor] = 2;
            });
        }
        function initializeElevatorsOnFloor(floor){
            elevatorOnFloor[floor] = 0;
        }



    // we initialize all the elevators    
    elevators.forEach(initializeElevator);
    // initialize the floors
    floors.forEach(initializeFloor);
    floors.forEach(initializeElevatorsOnFloor);

    },
    update: function(dt, elevators, floors) {
        // We normally don't need to do anything here
    }
}
```